# `respond_to` without block argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Presently I'm using `respond_to` like this.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {render layout: false }
end
```

I know a sentence like `respond_to {| format | format.html }` can be written `respond_to :html`.
But how can I write without first block if `format.html` also have a block argument?

I want to write like `respond_to :html, {render layout: false }`.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, it seems like your first example is the answer to your question.

Comment: You are right, my question was not clear at all. I adjusted my question. Is that now understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be you have this confused with `respond_with`?

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @people = Person.all
    respond_with @people
  end
end
```

`respond_with` can be configured just as `respond_to`:

```
respond_with(@people) do |format|
  format.html { render layout: false }
end
```

See the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with) or [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3) for more information about `respond_with`.